# Specify lag period with value of another column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have table and want get 2 another columns (column1 and column2) with expected values given below:

```
partition part_index value1 (column1) (column2)
1         1           1      1        null
1         2           1.5    1        null
1         3           3      1        null
1         4           5      1        null
1         5           6      1        null
2         1           5      5        6
2         2           2      5        6
2         3           3      5        6 
2         4           4      5        6
2         5           5      5        6
3         1           6      6        5
3         2           5.5    6        5
3         3           5      6        5
3         4           4.5    6        5 
3         5           4      6        5
4         1           6      6        4
4         2           10     6        4
4         3           2      6        4
4         4           3      6        4
4         5           4      6        4
```

I've tried get column1 by lag function with offset given by value of other column over specified window but I get error: TypeError: Column is not iterable. Below is my function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window
window1=Window.partitionBy("partition").orderBy("part_index")
data.withColumn("column1", f.lag(f.col("column1"),\
                                  f.col("part_index")-1)\
                                  .over(window1)).show()
```

How to specify offset by value of other column correctly?

Secondly, I want get column2 with last value of value1 from previous partition. I think the solution should be similar to 1st one but I don't know how to refer to the last value of previous partition for a given column.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the logic for column1 is first value of value1 in partition ordered by part_index column.
This is my solution:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f 
from pyspark.sql import Window
window_spec = Window.partitionBy('partition').orderBy('part_index').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
column2_window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy('partition').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
data = (data
        .withColumn('column1', f.first(f.col('value1')).over(window_spec))
        .withColumn('last_value_of_partition', f.last('value1').over(window_spec))
        .withColumn('last_values_list', f.collect_list('last_value_of_partition').over(column2_window))
        .withColumn('column2', f.element_at(f.expr('filter(last_values_list, element -> element <> last_value_of_partition)'), -1))
        .select(data['*'], 'column1', 'column2')
)
data.show()
```

input:

```
+---------+----------+------+                                                   
|partition|part_index|value1|
+---------+----------+------+
|        1|         1|     1|
|        1|         2|    11|
|        2|         1|     1|
|        2|         2|    12|
|        3|         1|     1|
|        3|         2|    13|
+---------+----------+------+
```

output:

```
+---------+----------+------+-------+-------+                                   
|partition|part_index|value1|column1|column2|
+---------+----------+------+-------+-------+
|        1|         1|     1|      1|   null|
|        1|         2|    11|      1|   null|
|        2|         1|     1|      1|     11|
|        2|         2|    12|      1|     11|
|        3|         1|     1|      1|     12|
|        3|         2|    13|      1|     12|
+---------+----------+------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yesterday Im luckly done it another way which I posted in another comment. I'm trying your solution tommorow evening.

Answer (score 0):

After some brainstorming yesterday evening I generated desired result by calculating 2 additional df_help dataframe and then joining them to main df.*time_index is my part_index which I use in main post. Below is my code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f 
from pyspark.sql import Window
#Specify window for 2 new columns
windowSpec_refPrice=Window.partitionBy("index")

#Calculate new column1 by creating new df_help and after joining to main df
df_help=dane.withColumn("min", f.min("index_time").over(windowSpec_refPrice))\
.where(f.col("index_time")==f.col("index_time")).select("index", "Value1")\
.withColumnRenamed("Value1", "Column1")
df=df.join(df_help, ["index"], how="inner")

#Calculate new column2 by creating new df_help and after joining to main df
df_help=dane.withColumn("max", f.max("index_time").over(windowSpec_refPrice))\
.where(f.col("index_time")==f.col("max")).select("index", "Value1")\
.withColumnRenamed("Value1", "Column2")
df_help=df_help.withColumn("Column2", f.lag("Column2", 1).over(Window.partitionBy(f.lit(1)).orderBy(f.lit(1))))\
.select("index", "Column2")
df=df.join(df_help, ["index"], how="inner")
```